# Writing Drizzle code to support two RDBMSs

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, drizzle

I am writing an Drizzle-based Typescript application that will use Postgres in production — but I would really like it to use Sqlite for most tests.  Is that even a possibility?

I notice that the examples highlight RDMBS-specific code.  For example, from the docs:

```
import {
  sqliteTable,
  integer,
  text,
  index,
  unique,
} from "drizzle-orm/sqlite-core";

export const users = sqliteTable("users", {
  id: integer("id").primaryKey({ autoIncrement: true }),
  username: text("username").unique().notNull(),
});
```

Well, that’s great, but how do I do the equivalent thing for both Sqlite *and* Postgres?  If I write two different schema files, which would not be unreasonable, how do I switch between using the different files?

Comment: It's definitely a possibility -- are there any constraints that would prove otherwise?  Especially if you're using an ORM, it's not to hard to flip from one to the other (take for example sqlAlchemy)

Comment: @richyen — thank you for your response, but this question is in the context of the Drizzle ORM, which has a lot of RDBMS-specific code.  I will update the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Using different database engines in testing and production is just asking for trouble when the test system allows something the production system doesn't.

Comment: I wish there were a StackOverflow option that indicated “Don’t tell me why I don’t want to do what I do in fact want to do.”  @Shawn — I realize there are some risks  involved in using a RDMB other than Postgres in testing, but in this case, they are offset by the risks involved in using Postgres in testing.